# Pyspark file not found error despite proper import

Tags: python, pyspark, import

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue with PySpark in my Anaconda3 environment. I followed the steps in this tutorial video (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C8kWso4ne4) to set up PySpark, but it's not working as expected. The problem is, I haven't configured any system variables, and I imported PySpark using Anaconda3.

I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting this problem. I'm unsure why things are not functioning correctly, and I hope it's just a simple error.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[screen with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkDGk.png)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)